# Make Mac program work without Window Server

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [avoid X11 forwarding from Mac to linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601180/avoid-x11-forwarding-from-mac-to-linux)

I want to make Mac program work even though there is no Window Server present. I need that because log in from a Linux machine and I don't need GUI (and the program still creates it even though it is not used). Right now I get the following error:

```
<Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
couldn't allocate new Mac window
```

Comment: Don't add new questions; edit your old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the GUI and there will be no dependency on it.

Split the program in parts: command-line version and GUI version. GUI may call command-line one to do the job (via `NSTask` arguments and/or `Distributed Objects`), or they may share a third bundle with the code that does the actual work.